# How use wro4j in play framework 2.1

Tags: playframework-2.1

there is a way to include wro4j http://code.google.com/p/wro4j/
in java play framework 2.1? 
i need to compile hogan.js templates and do much more 
without reinvent the route.
maybe i should use interceptors (@Before, @After, @Finally) and creating a class that extend Application?

regards

Answer (score 1):

wro4j process resources either at build time or at runtime.

I'm not aware of any Play2 integration/plugin/sample yet.

You can use the wro4j SBT plugin available here: https://github.com/BowlingX/xsbt-wro4j-plugin/

Or you could write a wro4j controller that process resources on the fly in DEV mode and cache them in PROD mode.