# Play Framework CSS/JS aggregation

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, minify

Is there a version of a press module (http://www.playframework.com/modules/press) for Play Framework 2 to minifi and aggregate JS and CSS? Are there alternatives? I hate 20 files being included into my templates.

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly do you mean by minify? Do you want less JS and CSS code or less files?

Comment: Well, it doesn't matter, but let's just start with I have 5 CSS files and 10 JS files, I want them to be combined and minified on the server side to produce 1 CSS file and 1 JS file. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could look into integrating wro4j into your build: https://code.google.com/p/wro4j/  It's quite flexible when it comes to combining js/css files.

Comment: Seems promising, thanks! Are there any resources on how would I go about doing that? I found this :( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14959594/how-use-wro4j-in-play-framework-2-1

Comment: Ah, you're building with sbt I see.  I use sbt for development (with wro4j in runtime mode), but maven and the wro4j maven plugin for "real" builds.  The sbt plugin you found seems promising though.

Comment: I am actually using the automated building that comes with Play, but I am just starting out, so I will need to figure out a real build system

Answer (score 2):

Play supports LESS directly, you can create one less file where you import all the needed CSS files. In this way you can get all your CSS in a single request.

Comment: That's a cool workaround, but sounds a bit hacky. I am looking for a Play equivalent of Cobres: https://github.com/buunguyen/combres

Comment: Well LESS is supported directly in the framework and this feature is also documented so I wouldn't consider it hackish.